# Unable to launch/start a java application(BURAI1.3.2)

Tags: java, javafx

I am facing the problem of not being able to launch the `burai.desktop` `burai.sh` application in spite of following all the steps of deleting existing java and reinstalling a new java version. After trying to launch through the terminal, the message shows:

```
Could not find or load main class burai.app.QEFXMain
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

for both `./burai.sh` and `java -jar burai.jar` commands.
What can I do?

Comment: which Ubuntu version are you using? What have you tried already?

Comment: I used the latest version of ubuntu i.e. 22.04